Pipeline Hazelcast with Dynamic Query SQL
I insert dynamically with an insert into the map created with Hazelcast
public void addMessage(MessageDTO message) {
 try {
 mapVirtualDevice.forEach((k, v) ->
 {
 List<HazelcastStatement> hazelcastStatements = v.getFct().processMessage(message, k, v);
 hazelcastStatements.forEach(hz -> hazelcast.getSql().execute(hz.getSqlStatement(), hz.getParameters()));
 }
 );
 } catch (Exception e) {
 log.error("Exception in addMessage for Message: " + message, e);
 throw and;
 }
 }

I have a pipeline that remains in Sync to the map and I aggregate in a custom way based on a variable. Is it possible to execute SQL queries in the pipeline? Otherwise I would have to implement every mathematical function
public Pipeline createPipeline(VirtualDevice virtualDevice, String virtualMap) {
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();

        return pipeline
                .readFrom(Sources.<String, VirtualDeviceImap>mapJournal(virtualMap,
                        JournalInitialPosition.START_FROM_OLDEST))
                .withTimestamps(l -> l.getValue().getSampleTimestamp().toInstant().toEpochMilli(), 0)
                .window(WindowDefinition.tumbling(virtualDevice.getAggregation() * 1000))
                .aggregate(AggregateOperations.toList())
                .map(windowResult -> {

                    TestMessage testMessage = new TestMessage();
                    List<MessageDTO> message =  createMessage(virtualDevice, windowResult.result());
                    testMessage.setMessageDTOList(message);
                    testMessage.setStartWindows(Instant.ofEpochMilli(windowResult.start()).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString());
                    testMessage.setEndWindows(Instant.ofEpochMilli(windowResult.end()).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString());
                    return testMessage;
                  
                })
                .writeTo(Sinks.files(""))
                .getPipeline();
    }


I am getting serialization error, as hazelcast.getConfig is not serializable.

Have you checked JdbcSinkBuilder ? You can write to multiple sinks in your pipeline. One of them could be a jdbc sink and you can execute SQL. Here is the link https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.3.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/jet/pipeline/JdbcSinkBuilder.html
